# Any way to test Blackberry 10 without paying for a license?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I downloaded the [blackberry 10 simulator](http://BlackBerry10Simulator-Installer-BB10_2_0X-1443-Mac-201308220135.dmg) on the [Blackberry developer site](https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/sim_index.html) and ran the installer.

The system requirements tell me to download [VMware Fusion 3.1 or later](http://store.vmware.com/DRHM/store?Action=DisplayProductDetailsPage&SiteID=vmware&Locale=en_US&ThemeID=2485600&Env=BASE&productID=285682300&?src=WWW_eBIZ_productpage_Fusion_Upgrade_US); this requires me to buy a license.

I did manage to get the 30 day free trial, but is anyone aware of a way to test Blackberry 10 for more than 30 days without paying for a license?

Thanks,

Albert.

Comment: You can also get yourself a BB10 device :)

Comment: What OS are you trying to develop on? I presume Mac, in which case you are correct - according to the requirements you must use Fusion, and it is going to cost you.  http://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/simulator_systemrequirements.html

Comment: Just noted this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701247/windows-7-on-virtualbox-virtual-machine-is-it-opengl-1-x-compatible

Answer (score 2):

Try use [VMware player](http://www.vmware.com/go/downloadplayer), I think it is free for non commercial use.

Comment: I think the answer does fit perfectly to the question. I'm running the latest simulator with a free version of VMware Player. You will have to check in detail, if the license agreement allows you to use the free version.

Comment: @iamanyone is right: VMWare Player is free, and it can run the newest simulators. It's a way to test apps without paying for a license, isn't it?

Comment: He is running OSX and there is no version of VMWare player for OSX. The only Mac VMWare product is Fusion. That one cost money, but again, building complex software for a niche OS where pressure from competitors is lower is also expensive.

Answer (score -1):

BB10 emulators on Windows *used* to need VirtualBox. Recently (*between 10 Gold and 10.2 beta*) they switched to VMware player.

Makes a lot of sense for Blackberry, (simplify support), sucks if you don't want to pay for a license.

So to answer your question:

#### Is there a way to test Blackberry 10 for more than 30 days without paying for a license?

**No**, if you want a supported environment and want to be able to debug/troubleshoot your apps the way the BB team envisioned it.

**Yes**, or at least Maybe, it used to work on VirtualBox, I'll bet it still does. 
Your trial version of VMWare should be able to export VMs to the OVA/OVF format.

- VirtualBox is able to import an OVA/OVF VM.
- VirtualBox is also able to mount an VMWare hard-drive.
- You will have to fiddle with settings of every component, (but if you still have VMware * fusion, you can try to replicate the emulated machine architecture) and I do think you'll lose "Controller.app" connectivity (the small app that allows to simulate sensors).
- The VM auto-detection may not work, but the link uses SSH... So if you can ping it, you will be able to debug it.

If it works, consider exporting the VirtualBox VM and sharing it. (or maybe instructions)

Comment: Are you talking the Mac, Linux or Windows?  I can only comment on Windows.  In Windows the above does not match my experience.  I was involved fairly early on (pre release of 10.0) in BB10 development and I have always used VMware Player, I am currently using 5.something and it is free, forever as far as I can see.  I have never used VirtualBox for BB development (have used it for other things) nor seen any BBRY documentation that referenced it.

Comment: Looks like you are right. I was *so sure* I was using VirtualBox... Weird. Anyway, I'm using VMWare Fusion now, but... So weird. Thanks for correcting me !