# Windows 7 on Virtualbox virtual machine: is it OpenGL 1.x compatible?

Tags: windows, opengl, blackberry, virtualbox

Nowhere in my VirtualBox virtual machine settings for a Windows 7 guest (or in the system information) can I find out if my virtual video card is OpenGL 1.x compatible.

I need OpenGL 1.x compatibility in order to test with [the BlackBerry 7 simulator](http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/the_bb_smrtphn_simulator_447179_11.html).

Does the VirtualBox default generic video card support OpenGL 1.x?

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your guest VM will be able to run OpenGL 1.x and newer.

Install the VirtualBox Guest Additions via the "Devices" menu in the virtual machine's menu bar

> VirtualBox has a handy menu item named "Install guest additions", which mounts the Guest Additions ISO file inside your virtual machine

This will enable 3D hardware acceleration in your guest machine (OpenGL and Direct3D 8/9).

VirtualBox states that

> because 3D support is still experimental at this time, it is disabled by default and must be **manually enabled** in the VM settings

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-3d

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about higher versions of OpenGL? Do you know anything about that?

Comment: I'm curious too. Guess not.