# Blackberry simulator: can't lower graphics settings in view menu

Tags: opengl, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I downloaded the simulator for BB Bold 9930 (v. 7.1) at  http://us.blackberry.com/sites/developers/resources/simulators.html

My Windows VM follows the system requirements at http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/the_bb_smrtphn_simulator_447179_11.html, except for one thing: OpenGL 1.x compatibility, which I can't figure out how to test (see [Windows 7 on Virtualbox virtual machine: is it OpenGL 1.x compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701247)).

So installing this and launching C:\Program Files\Research In Motion......\9930.bat causes the following error to come up:

"An OpenGL 1.x + compatible video card with recent video drivers is required for graphics acceleration. Please try a lower graphics acceleration setting by navigating to the view menu".

Clicking on the view menu is impossible until I click OK on the modal dialog, but when I do so, the program immediately crashes with the message "BlackBerry Handheld Simulator has stopped working".

Is there any way around (through the command line, for instance?)

Comment: Seriously? You repost the same question barely half an hour later?

Comment: @alberto56, remember to vote for, and accept, answers that help you, by using the buttons to the left of the answers.  This helps other people know which solutions worked, thanks people for helping you, and identifies which questions have been solved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to force the simulator **not** to use the graphics acceleration at all (which hopefully would work around your problem).

[See this BlackBerry forum thread here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/What-is-the-fledge-command-line-argument-to-control-the-Graphics/m-p/674983/highlight/true#M136027).

Basically, just include this in your simulator config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fledge-configuration>
  <BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>0</BodyBuilder::opengl-acceleration>
```

The setting of `0` turns off graphics acceleration.   You can either turn it off by default in your simulators, or just in one particular simulator, by using the fledge-saved.conf file, or 9900-saved.conf file (for example, to change the setting on the 9900 simulator).

On a Windows system, these config files would be located somewhere like:

```xml
C:\Users\myname\net\rim\fledge-2\
```